# jquery tool tip not responding on my website but works fine in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone please help me..

Here's my fiddle.. works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/supplement/j77eB/

Now when i post my code to my website like so...

```
<head>  

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style type="text/css">
      label {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 5em;
      }
      .red {
          color: red;
      }
    }
    </style></head>

<script>$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        },
        show: null, 
        close: function (event, ui) {
            ui.tooltip.hover(

            function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
            },

            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            });
        }
    });
});</script>

<p><a href="#" title="<span class='red'>This is a <a href='#'>link</a></span>">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. 
    When you hover the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, 
    just like a native.</p>
```

It doesn't work...

is it something with my links?

Comment: What does your console log say?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . jquery-ui.css:8
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip' tooltip.php:19

Comment: Those are my only two errors on my console log.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"></script>
```

You are referencing a CSS file as a JS.

Presumable you mean to have:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```